# How to un-pivot data in a table on Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I've read the suggested results pertaining to un-pivoting a table using the method from a Jon Walkenbach article, but I'm on a Mac, and can't get the desired result.

My scenario is exactly the same as found in the article:
[Transform horizontal table layout to vertical table](https://superuser.com/questions/683413/transform-horizontal-table-layout-to-vertical-table/684935#684935)
so I'll just refer to those same field names and procedure steps here.

Since I don't have access to an "old pivot table menu" in macOS (as far as I know), I don't have the same options listed there. When I try to use the tools at my disposal, I get Field Names corresponding to ID, Name1, Name2, Name3, with a checkbox for each, rather than the desired Row, Column, Value.

If I uncheck everything but ID, I do get a single-cell pivot table, but double-clicking on that cell produces the exact same table that I started out with.

I was able to obtain the desired results using Excel on Windows 10 to test it and make sure I was understanding it correctly. But trying the same steps on the Mac, I can't get it to work. One answer might be "Use a PC." But if there's another answer, I'd love it. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting find. I suspect the Pivot Wizard has long since been updated and that process in your link no longer works. If power query is available to you in Mac-Excel there is an unpivot function. I have to check if lambda functions are available for Mac-Excel, but the formula I came up with was a little long if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 365, you can use a formula (and, according to the documentation, the functions I am using are available in 365 MAC)

I used a table named `Table5` and copied it from the example you linked to, but you could use regular addressing if you had to.

Also, as in that example, I assumed you wanted a two column result, with the first column being repeated:

```
=LET(
    cols, COLUMNS(Table5) - 1,
    rows, ROWS(Table5),
    v, TOCOL(DROP(Table5, , 1)),
    ID, INDEX(
        Table5[ID],
        INT((SEQUENCE(rows * cols) - 1) / cols + 1)
    ),
    stack, VSTACK({"ID", "Name"}, HSTACK(ID, v)),
    FILTER(stack, CHOOSECOLS(stack, 2) <> "")
)
```

In the above:

- `cols`: number of columns to unpivot (total columns in table -1)
- `rows`: number of data rows
- `v`: a vertical array of the unpivoted columns
- `ID`: a vertical array of the `ID` column (column1) with each entry repeated by the number of rows we are unpivoting
- `stack`: the column headers and the two vertical columns are stacked into a result table
- That result is then filtered to remove the blank entries

***Data***
[image]

***Unpivoted***
[image]

If you do not have those functions, you can use Power Query and you can access the unpivot function from the GUI.