# Transform Table Format From Vertical to Horizontal

Tags: microsoft-excel

I found a similar post to what I want to achieve but the other way around
[Transform horizontal table layout to vertical table](https://superuser.com/questions/683413/transform-horizontal-table-layout-to-vertical-table)

I want to transform this

| City | Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| City A | Company `A` | Address `A` |
| City B | Company `B` | Address `B` |
| City A | Company `C` | Address `C` |
| City B | Company `D` | Address `D` |

to this

|  | Name_1 | Address_1 | Name_2 | Address_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City A | Company `A` | Address `A` | Company `C` | Address `C` |
| City B | Company `B` | Address `B` | Company `D` | Address `D` |

I tried Pivot Table but I can't display the name on rows inline to its City. Its just returning numbers. I've been stuck on it for hours but I just can't find a way to do it using Pivot Table. TIA.

Comment: Excel pivot table wants to aggregate items you put in the values section that is the reason you are getting numbers. You'll either need to use formulas OR power query with some type of pivoting. When you pivot there should be an option Don't aggregate...

Comment: Power Query can Transform data in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this using a Pivot Table in Excel.

However, this can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table46"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"City", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Address", type text}}),

//unpivot Name/Address columns 
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"City"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Group by City
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"City"}, {

    //for each subgroup (City)
        {"all", (t)=>let 

        //Add a numeric suffix to the Attributes to create the new column names
            #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(t,"idx",0,1,Int64.Type),
            #"Number Suffix" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Index", "Divide", each "_" & Text.From(Number.IntegerDivide([idx],2)+1)),
            #"Remove idx" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Number Suffix",{"idx"}),
            #"Col Hdrs" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Remove idx",{"Attribute","Divide"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(""),"Attribute"),

        //then pivot on the column header column
            #"Pivot Table" = Table.Pivot(#"Col Hdrs", List.Distinct(#"Col Hdrs"[Attribute]), "Attribute","Value")
        in 
            #"Pivot Table", type table}}),

//create a list of all the column Names
    #"All Column Headers" = List.Distinct(
        List.Accumulate(
            #"Grouped Rows"[all],
            {},
            (state, current)=> state & List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(current),1)
        )),

//Expand the Table (all) column
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all", #"All Column Headers"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded all",List.Transform(#"All Column Headers", each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]